# Cannot connect to Eureka server. Exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, microservices, netflix-eureka

I was doing microservices tutorial from javabrains.io and everything was ok till I tried to implement Eureka server in one of microservices.

My main class is simple:

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.server.EnableEurekaServer;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class DiscoveryServerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DiscoveryServerApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

my POM looks like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>pl.Grzesiek</groupId>
    <artifactId>discovery-server</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>discovery-server</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>



    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Setup Spring MVC & REST, use Embedded Tomcat -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
            <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <!-- Spring Cloud dependencies -->
    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Finchley.RELEASE</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

After I run the app I got huge exception note (I post only the beginning) :

```
2019-05-13 16:42:36.026  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.core.annotation.AnnotationUtils      : Failed to introspect annotations on class org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.config.EurekaDiscoveryClientConfigServiceBootstrapConfiguration: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not obtain annotation attribute value for public abstract java.lang.Class[] org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.ConditionalOnClass.value()
    2019-05-13 16:42:37.057  INFO 8704 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'configurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99f95863] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)

    .   ____          _            __ _ _
    /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
    ( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
    \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
    '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
    =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
    :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.1.4.RELEASE)

    2019-05-13 16:42:37.885  INFO 8704 --- [           main] p.G.d.DiscoveryServerApplication         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
    2019-05-13 16:42:39.885  WARN 8704 --- [           main] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
    2019-05-13 16:42:40.542  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=0a227739-edaa-382b-b6cd-a363789789b9
    2019-05-13 16:42:40.776  INFO 8704 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$99f95863] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
    2019-05-13 16:42:41.792  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
    2019-05-13 16:42:41.854  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
    2019-05-13 16:42:41.854  INFO 8704 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.17]
    2019-05-13 16:42:42.573  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
    2019-05-13 16:42:42.573  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 4656 ms
    2019-05-13 16:42:42.917  WARN 8704 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
    2019-05-13 16:42:42.917  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
    2019-05-13 16:42:43.057  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@413bef78
    2019-05-13 16:42:46.370  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.s.j.s.i.a.WebApplicationImpl           : Initiating Jersey application, version 'Jersey: 1.19.1 03/11/2016 02:08 PM'
    2019-05-13 16:42:46.541  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2019-05-13 16:42:46.541  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
    WARNING: Illegal reflective access by com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields (file:/C:/Users/Grzegorz/.m2/repository/com/thoughtworks/xstream/xstream/1.4.10/xstream-1.4.10.jar) to field java.util.TreeMap.comparator
    WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of com.thoughtworks.xstream.core.util.Fields
    WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
    WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
    2019-05-13 16:42:46.854  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
    2019-05-13 16:42:46.854  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
    2019-05-13 16:42:47.666  WARN 8704 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.a.ArchaiusAutoConfiguration      : No spring.application.name found, defaulting to 'application'
    2019-05-13 16:42:47.666  WARN 8704 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
    2019-05-13 16:42:47.666  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
    2019-05-13 16:42:47.995  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
    2019-05-13 16:42:48.916  INFO 8704 --- [           main] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
    2019-05-13 16:42:48.994  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.354  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON encoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.354  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using JSON decoding codec LegacyJacksonJson
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.354  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.354  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.604  INFO 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
    2019-05-13 16:42:49.948  INFO 8704 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
    2019-05-13 16:42:52.135 ERROR 8704 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient  : Request execution error

    com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.get(WebResource.java:509) ~[jersey-client-1.19.1.jar:1.19.1]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplicationsInternal(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:194) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.jersey.AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.getApplications(AbstractJerseyEurekaHttpClient.java:165) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(MetricsCollectingEurekaHttpClient.java:73) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.executeOnNewServer(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:118) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.execute(RedirectingEurekaHttpClient.java:79) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:120) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) ~[eureka-client-1.9.2.jar:1.9.2]
at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:63) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:269) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$a1625182.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
```

And its go on...

Anyone had the same problem? I have no idea what could be the reason.

a what is the reason... Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Please add these properties to your application properties or yml file.

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false   
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
```

**Update:**

If the above config does not works try with camelCase.

```
eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false
```

**YAML Version:**

```
eureka:
  client:
    fetchRegistry: 'false'
    registerWithEureka: 'false'
```

**Explanation:**

We're telling the built-in Eureka Client not to register with itself because our application should be acting as a server.

Comment: Thanks! I had exactly the same issue. Any reason why it's happening though?

Comment: The reason behind this error is Eureka client is trying to register and fetch information with Eureka servere. This happens because of bean auto configuration feature in spring Boot. As you are deploying the Eureka server you don't need want to register with yourself. That's why we are disabling.

Comment: if it still doesn't work. try using camelCase:  
`eureka.client.registerWithEureka=false
eureka.client.fetchRegistry=false`
I had to do this in order to get rid of that error, don't ask me why, I don't know. it just works.

Comment: If none of the above works and you're using YAML, check the indentation

Comment: I added above 2 properties to properties file (camelCase one) and also had to add server.port=8761 to use that as a default port for Eureka.. I was using it on STS v4 on Mac pro.

Answer (score 4):

Adding the below property to application.properties file for the clients worked (without adding the defaultZone property):

`eureka.instance.hostname=localhost`

It seems the Eureka clients were not able to identify the hostname of the Eureka Server by default, and hence it is to be manually configured.

Comment: I had similiar problem, and your soultion works for me, thank you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just set your eureka server port to 8761 (the default one):

```
server.port = 8761
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove:

```
<dependency>
   <!-- Spring Cloud starter -->
   <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

With `spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server` is enough, but remove also the version 1.4.6.RELEASE, that is controlled by the `dependencyManagement`.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, however it does not put any impact on running the app.

Answer (score 0):

Even after updating your application.properties to stop self-register if it does not work, then I thought you have added the serviceUrl property even though this property makes a hit for registration.

```
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

⬆️Don't add the above property to your **EUREKA SERVER APPLICATION**